# Using model attributes in a th:href link

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there a way of referencing a model attribute in a th:href link? For example

```
<a th:text="${currentUser}" th:href="@{/user/{currentUser}}"></a>
```

Here, *currentUser* is a model variable as specified in a controller. This can be accessed easily as seen in the *th:text* tag. However, the *th:href* fails the thymeleaf parsing. If there any way of referencing a model attribute in this way, in the *th:href*? For reference, this is a Spring MVC (bootstrap) application with Thymeleaf support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to include a model variable in `th:href` you have to include it with the `${...}` indicator, you could use the pipes to easily concatenate:

```
<a th:text="${currentUser}" th:href="@{|/user/${currentUser}|}"></a>
```

Official documentation on url syntax [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you Patrick - had no idea Thymeleaf supported string concatenation in that way