# Spring Boot: How refer CSS by Thymeleaf without matter if spring.mvc.servlet.path was defined or not?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

For Spring Boot 2.4.1, based on Web with Thymeleaf.

Having:

```
src/main/resources
   static
      css
         general.css
```

And the `application.properties` file having:

```
# Web Properties
server.servlet.context-path=/spring-boot-draft
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/demo
```

Therefore the app can be accessed through `http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-draft/demo`. Until here it works fine as is expected.

The situation is the following, for a html page based with Thymeleaf to refer a css file, is defined:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/general.css}" />`

But it does not work, must be used instead:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/demo/css/general.css}" />`

From above observe the `/demo` part comes from `spring.mvc.servlet.path`. Again it is mandatory. But has no sense put that `/demo` part explicitly, consider change later the `spring.mvc.servlet.path` value.

What setting is need it in Spring Boot in the `application.properties` file to use in peace
`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/general.css}" />` without matter if `spring.mvc.servlet.path` was defined or not?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### One

add in the model something such as:

```
model.addAttribute("spring_mvc_servlet_path",
                    environment.getProperty("spring.mvc.servlet.path"));
```

**Note**: do *not* use how a key `spring.mvc.servlet.path`, it because later Thymeleaf through `${spring.mvc.servlet.path}` throws an error assuming that `mvc` is a property of `spring`. It is the reason about why `spring_mvc_servlet_path` is used instead.

#### Second

Use

`<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{|${spring_mvc_servlet_path}/css/general.css|}" />`

Observe:

- the String concatenation through the pipes.
- use the `${spring_mvc_servlet_path}`

This post was useful:

- [Using model attributes in a th:href link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084927/using-model-attributes-in-a-thhref-link)